# Redistribute resgen

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resgen

Anyone know whether you can redistribute resgen.exe as part of your application?  There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

arg. i should have dug deeper.  Looks like ResourceWriter does the same thing and I have no need to redistribute it.

Answer (score 0):

More likely than not, it has to be distributed with the .NET framework due to the EULA, so you would have to distribute the full install of .NET for whatever version of the framework you want to run resgen with.